# How do I use a value that is owned by a match statement in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership, borrowing

My intention is to match the value of every line in a text file. If the value matches a string, the corresponding opcode should be pushed to a vector. Otherwise, I want to add the value itself to the vector. The value itself cannot be used because it belongs to another scope.

Correct be if I'm wrong, but I cannot copy or clone the value of `line` because it doesn't implement the correct traits. What is the best solution to borrow the value in the match statement and then use it as the default (`_`) in case it does not match any string?

```
let buffered = BufReader::new(input);

for line in buffered.lines() {
    match line.unwrap().as_ref() {
        "nop" => instructions.push(0x00),
        "push" => instructions.push(0x01),
        "print" => instructions.push(0x02),
        "add" => instructions.push(0x03),
        "halt" => instructions.push(0xff),
        _ => instructions.push(line.unwrap().as_bytes()[0]),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arbitrary value instead of `_`. The statement now looks like this:

```
for line in buffered.lines() {
    match line.unwrap().as_ref() {
        "nop" => instructions.push(0x00),
        "push" => instructions.push(0x01),
        "print" => instructions.push(0x02),
        "add" => instructions.push(0x03),
        "halt" => instructions.push(0xff),
        x => instructions.push(x.as_bytes()[0]),
    }
}
```